# Actionscript 3 - Image not showing when printed

Tags: actionscript-3, printing, movieclip, flash-cs6

I have a png image on top of any elements that are added to the working area. The user can click and drag new elements to the area and then print the picture they create. The png image is not moveable. The png image acts as a background image or like a container for the user's picture.

When I try to print it, the png image does not show. I get the elements to show nicely, but that is it. If I change a few things I am able to print only the png image and not the elements. How do I get them to print together?

```
//This puts my png image on top and unclickable
stage.addChild(seal);
seal.mouseEnabled = false;

//this brings the current element to the front
for (var fl_ChildIndex_5:int = 0;
    fl_ChildIndex_5 < this.numChildren;
    fl_ChildIndex_5++) {
    this.getChildAt(fl_ChildIndex_5).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToBringToFront_5);
}
function fl_ClickToBringToFront_5(event:MouseEvent):void {
    this.addChild(event.currentTarget as DisplayObject);
}

//This is my print button
var button:Sprite = new Sprite();
button.graphics.beginFill(0xf67821, 1);
button.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 120, 60);
button.graphics.endFill();
addChild(button);

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, printContent);

var myArea:MovieClip = root as MovieClip;
var myRectangle:Rectangle = new Rectangle(150,0,700,500);

function printContent(event:MouseEvent) {
   var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
   if (printJob.start()) {
       if (myArea.width > printJob.pageWidth){
           myArea.width = printJob.pageWidth;
           myArea.scaleY = myArea.scaleX;
           {printAsBitmap:true};
       }
       printJob.addPage(myArea, myRectangle);
    }
    printJob.send();
    printJob = null;
}
```

**NEWEST CODE**

```
var workingarea:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
stage.addChild(workingarea);

var seal:Sprite = new Sprite();
seal = new SealImg();
seal.x = 475;
seal.y = 271;
workingarea.addChild(seal);

seal.mouseEnabled = false;
seal.mouseChildren = false;
```

Comment: your image is on the stage and you are printing the root (which is not the stage).

Comment: What BotMaster says. Try creating a base movie clip on the stage and then add all your content to the base clip. In general, its better for many reasons to avoid using things like root or stage or frame 1 for that matter and instead use something you instantiated.

Comment: I tried to create a base movie clip for my content to go into so I can then print it. That seems to be working, but now my image won't stay on top of the elements. 

See new code above.